# Where should I write my database credentials in node.js app?

Tags: configuration, database, node.js

I'm deploying my node.js app, which is based on Ghost, on Google Compute Engine. However, I'm not sure whether it is a good behavior to write my database credentials in `config.js`.

The `config.js` file is something like the follows:

```
...
'production': {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2368',
    database: {
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host     : '127.0.0.1',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'root',
            database : 'ghost',
            charset  : 'utf8'
        }
    },
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: '2368'
    },
},...
```

However, this includes the database credentials hard-coded in `config.js`. I'm not sure if this is secure enough in production.

Should I be better off to set the credentials using environment variables from `process.env.xxx` (e.g. `process.env.DB_USER`)? In that case, what is the best way to write those environment variables in a file and run the app with the configuration?

Answer (score 4):

You should never put the credentials in any file that goes to the source code repository.

What is usually done is to use environment variables that are set using a control panel of your hosting platform for a simplest solution, or you can use tools like etcd for more flexible solution. See:

- https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/

With Node you can also use the dotenv module to make setting the env vars easier during development. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv